# NgRX Store from a library component: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Store -> Store]

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-library

I am working on an Angular application that incorporates a library, which utilizes NgRx's `StoreModule`. The `StoreModule` is initialized within the application, and I aim to consume the state within the library since multiple projects will share the same component.

The setup functions correctly when the library resides in the same project. However, an error arises when the library is situated in an external folder:

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Store -> Store]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Store!
```

Interestingly, if I merely copy the compiled files from the dist folder and amend the tsconfig, it operates as expected. But, it fails to work from a distant folder.

Here's a snippet of the code from the App:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<lib-test></lib-test>`,
})
export class AppComponent {}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [StoreModule.forRoot({}), BrowserModule, TestComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

On the Library:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-test',
  standalone: true,
  template: `test`,
})
export class TestComponent {
  constructor(private store: Store) {}
}
```

My paths on tsconfig.json

```
"paths": {
  "@angular/*": ["./node_modules/@angular/*"],
  // "test-lib": ["dist/test-lib"], // This works
  "test-lib": ["../test-library/dist/test-lib"], // This will not work (same compiled files)
}
```

I am seeking a way to resolve this error and successfully share the StoreModule between the app and the external library.

Comment: Use provideStore, read through this issue [Github Issue](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/3700#issuecomment-1443854344) for some caveats whilst you're mixing NgModules and standalone

Comment: I tried with `provideStore(testReducer)`, with and without standalone, but nothing seems to work. I tried to symlink the library, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to hack my way through a solution, not a super elegant solution, but I'll post a bug report on NgRX and will update this answer when I'll find a better way.

Earlier I tried to symlink the dist folder as it is working when I copy the content, but that had the same result. So instead I symlinked the projects/test-lib folder and copied the library's configuration from the `angular.json` on the library's project to the new project.